# SQLAlchemy filter for files in a folder-file type hierarchy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, hierarchical-data

I have seen some pure SQL queries that could be solutions to this, but my SQL isn't really on point so a SQLAlchemy solution would be appreciated. I'm also using sqlite.

I have a hierarchy type structure in SQLAlchemy similar to a normal filesystem - nested nodes with leaves at the end. I have a solution for finding files using only Python, but it is quite slow so I'm hoping there's a faster way.

The folders are defined as such:

```
class folder(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'folder'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parentid = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('folder.id', ondelete='CASCADE'),index=True)
    type = Column(Text(50))

    children = relationship('folder',
                            cascade='all',
                            backref=backref('parent', remote_side='folder.id'),
                        )

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'folder',
        'polymorphic_on': type
    }

    def getFiles(self):
        """ returns a list of the files in this folder
        """
        flist = []
        for child in self.children:
            flist += child.getFiles()
        return flist
```

And the files:

```
class file(folder):
    __tablename__ = 'file'
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('folder.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text(50))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'file',
        'inherit_condition': (id == folder.id),
    }

    def getFiles(self):
        """ return self as the only file
        """
        return [self]
```

Currently I find files by filename like so:

```
files = some_folder.getFiles()
return [f for f in files if file_name in f.name.lower()]
```

Is there any better way to query for files in a folder?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to build a query exactly how I wanted, but playing around I found a solution that was much faster. Instead of finding all the files and then searching, I traverse to each folder and query for files in it. It resulted in quite a performance boost.

```
def search_files(folderid, search):
    files = session.query(file).filter(
                                    file.parentid==folderid,
                                    file.name.ilike('%{}%'.format(search))).all()
    folders = session.query(folder.ID).filter_by(parentid=folderid).all()
    for folder in folders:
        files+=search_files(folder.id, search)

    return files
```